# Favicon don´t show up in Google search result?

Tags: html, css, icons, favicon

Would anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong with my favicon. As you can see in the picture, my icon doesn't want to show up on Google search results.

My site is: [Econello](https://www.econello.com/sv/lana-pengar/)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This can be an on-site or off-site issue.

**On-site**

`https://www.econello.com/favicon.ico` is a 0 byte resource. Since loading `/favicon.ico` is a well-known convention, Google might try to use it. To fix this issue, remove this file from your web site or populate it with a real icon.

This point aside, Google seems to load your icon correctly, check `https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.econello.com`. As a second check, you can view your site in the Google Search Console, where Google displays your favicon, too. Note that the Google Search Console is "faster" than the search engine itself: your icon may appear in GSC, then in Google's RP later.

**Off-site**

This feature completely depends on Google's good will.

If your site is not popular enough, Google might just never care to display its favicon in its result pages. Even if it has crawled your favicon.

Having your favicon displayed by Google takes time. It can easily takes more than a week, even if your site is reasonably popular (eg. a few hundreds of visits per day from Google).

Comment: I have tried to find the URL file "https://www.econello.com/favicon.ico". But I can´t find it. Where can I find it? Thanks

Comment: That's a nice Google favicon tool I didn't know about, thanks!

Comment: @MarcelloRongione I suggest you to contact your hosting provider and ask about this empty favicon.

Comment: The Google url check isn't foolproof. Just a handful of sites into testing, I've already come across multiple whose favicons appear without issue in actual Google search results while they're missing at that url. Here's one example: https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=thamrinnine.com